# unexpected socket sometimes closes (or do not open)

Tags: java, sockets

I create a class that allows me to open a single instance of my Java program. It uses a daemon thread that open a ServerSocket. if the TCP Port was already taken throws an exception at instantiation time.

The code works normally under linux and windows.

Here is the code i am using:

```
public class SingleInstaceHandler extends Thread {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(IEPLC_Tool.class);
    private boolean finished = false;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;

    /*
     * Constructor
     * Generate the server socket.
     * If the TCP door was busy throws IOException.
     */
    public SingleInstaceHandler() throws IOException {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(44331);
        this.setDaemon(true);
        this.start();
        log.info("Server socket initialized"); //if commented out it works
    }

    public void run() {
        synchronized (this) {
            while (!finished) {
                try {
                    log.debug("Server socket goes to sleep");
                    this.wait();
                    log.debug("Server socket waken up");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    log.debug("ERROR while sending SocketThread2 in wait status");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.exit(-1);
                }
                log.info("Server socket end");
            }
        }
    }

    public synchronized void shutdown() {
        log.debug("SingleInstaceHandler shutdown() caled");
        finished = true;
        notifyAll();
    }
}
```

Sometimes instead the port is not kept busy... any idea?

---

UPPENDED AFTER FURTHER TESTS:

running many other tests. it seams that if the port is taken by something like another SW instance `new ServerSocket(44331);` throws an exception but sometimes even if the port is not taken for some reason it can not get this resource. in this case no exception is launched and i can open as many instance as i want of my application. maybe i should do some other operation to force the thread to lock the port...

any idea?

Thanks,

Ste

Comment: How do you diagnose that the socket is kept closed? Why do you have an unused serverSocket field in your class?

Comment: This code does not make sense to me. Why don't you store the `ServerSocket` in an instance variable, you can't never access it again?

Comment: i use the command netstat -vatn | grep "44331". i use it to guarantee a single instance ofmy application

Comment: normally if you want to guarantee not to instance of the same software to be used you have 2 solution. A lock file or lock over a socket. i am using the second one. but i have nothing to be sent... it's just for having the door busy. the second instance wil crash in opening the dor and therefore will be closed guaranteeing a single software instance

Comment: So you have a problem with your logging framework. I just run the code, but replaced the Logger with `java.util.logging.Logger` and it worked.

Comment: i am using org.apache.log4J.Logger. i just noticed that if i use log.debug instead of log.info it works... there is something really strange in there!

Comment: sorry... in the code i put log.debug instead of info... i fixed it...

Comment: I know this might be irrelevant but have you tried this: `Logger.getLogger(SingleInstaceHandler.class);`

Comment: mmm i am afraid the problem is somewhere else... :( i was trying putting and removing the logger and seems to be this.... but now once it did not work een with no logger... sorry! it seasm that somethimes the port is not kept busy!... strange!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do feel a bit stupid in posting an answer to my question... well.. my code has a bug that took me long to figure out:

the problem is that in te constructor i do:

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(44331);
```

instead of:

```
this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket(44331);
```

I did not notice it before... basicaly the bug was that I was declaring a local socket within the constructor. When the constructur procedure was terminated the socket was released or not depending on the Garbadge Collector. Behavior was quite random. Funny part was that plenty of time calling/not calling the logger was enougth to make the Garbadge collector starting or not. It took me quite a while in noticing the mistake.

furthermore it's better to put a :

`this.serverSocket.close()` after the wait.

Thans for helping anyway!

Cheers,

Ste

Answer (score 0):

As you are not keeping a reference to the ServerSocket it will be eligible for GC. If you are using the Oracle JDK the socket will be closed when it is GCed (java.net.PlainSocketImpl).